# Predicting repeated binary response from contacts over time

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, survival, binary-data, recurrent-events

From their initial entry date, people must be contacted each month for three months. It often takes several unsuccessful attempts before you establish contact. Once you reach someone, contact attempts stop for the month and resume the following month. Contact attempts are not evenly spaced, and the number of attempts may vary between people. One person responds on the first attempt, another requires five attempts before a response, while another doesn't respond to seven attempts.

Let $y_{i t k(t)}$ denote whether participant $i$  responded during the $k^{th}$ contact attempt in month $t$. For a concrete example, suppose participant $i$ had the following sequence of events:

- They were contacted twice in month 1. The first attempt was usuccessful. The second attempt was successful.

  - $y_{i 1 1} = 0$ and $y_{i 1 2} = 1$
- In month 2 there were four unsuccessful attempts to reach this person.

  - $y_{i21} = 0, \space  \dots, \space  y_{i24} = 0$
- In month 3, they responded on the first attempt.

  - $y_{i 3 1} = 1$

The goal is to predict if a particular contact attempt will be successful,  given their response history and baseline covariates, $X_i$.

In some ways, this seems like a discrete-time survival model: Given a person has not yet responded at attempt $k$, what is the probability they *will* respond at attempt $k+1$. However,  it doesn't exactly fit into this framework. There may be several contact attempts within a month, and these attempts are unevenly spaced in time. Also, the recurrent events (response in month 2 to 4), don't fit neatly into any survival models I'm aware of.

Can anyone recommend an approach to this problem? I am open to model-based approaches or black box machine learning style approaches.

Comment: A Markov chain? Or a logistic regression, with some calculated features like: success at last attempt? Any earlier success? proportion of earlier successes? What is your sample size? Number of individuals $i$? Other covariates? ...

Comment: There are some books that might help:  https://bookshop.org/books/modelling-recurrent-event-data-with-application-to-cancer-research/9783836474641,  https://bookshop.org/books/the-statistical-analysis-of-recurrent-events-2007/9781441924155

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have a very large dataset. It’s big enough to fit a complicated model if necessary.